# Unable to implement QR code Reader in my android app

Tags: android, qr-code

I am trying to implement a QR code reader in my android app. I have followed these steps:

1. Created a sample library project from the zxing.zip , /android and /core
2. Added the created library to my app

My code is as below :

```
public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button scanButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

The scanner doesn't start and I get this error:

```
05-08 14:12:03.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(718): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.scanner.demo-2.apk]
```

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.scanner.demo" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".main" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Could you specify the actual question you are asking please? How does it fail? Where does it fail?

Comment: @NeilTownsend The scanner doesnt start and i get this error:05-08 14:12:03.313: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(718): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.scanner.demo-2.apk]

Comment: If you are, as pointed out by @Sean Owen, incorporating third party code into your app, it is important to (a) stick to the way they suggest doing it and (b) make sure you are not violating the copyright on the packages. Even if what you are trying to do might be technically possible, it's not the way to do it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you put this in your Manifest?

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
...
</activity>
```

Are you calling internal activity or the App from Zxing?

Comment: I have made a library project which has the Zxing app

Comment: Yes, this is the error. Nobody should ever be declaring *our app* in their manifest.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite confused. You seem to be wanting to integrate by `Intent`, which is what the first half does. But then you seem to have copied our Manifest. Why? Please remove that. It's not needed, causes your error, and if you leave it in, interferes with our app.

This is all you need: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: I am still getting this error after removing the code from the manifest:                                                            05-08 14:39:55.970: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(859): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.scanner.demo-2.apk]

Comment: Can someone give me the steps to solve my problem. Some code maybe

Comment: I have followed these examples: http://www.androidaz.com/development/zxing-qr-reader-direct-integration , http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Comment: The point is: you don't use this class, you don't copy it. Right? You still seem confused about whether you want to use intents or not.

Comment: I just need to open a QR Code scanner on a button click. Get the scanned result

Comment: My main problem is my app cannot get the classes in my library project i have created. I have followed this step right click on projrct->Properties->Android->Add->select Library project ->ok.